# Can we add two objects by overloading - operator

Tags: c++11

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Complex { 
private: 
    int real, imag; 
public: 
    Complex(int r = 0, int i =0)  {real = r;   imag = i;} 
    Complex operator-(Complex const &obj) { 
         Complex res; 
         res.real = real + obj.real; 
         res.imag = imag + obj.imag; 
         return res; 
    } 
    void print() { 
        cout << real << " + i" << imag << endl; 
    }   
}; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4); 
    Complex c3 = c1 - c2; 
    c3.print(); 
}
```

**I am using `operator -` to add two objects**
I am changing the main functionality of the - sign.
This code is running perfectly and adding the real and imaginary part together

Comment: Feel free to overload operators, even though it is very, very misleading.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, especially if your intent is to make your code confusing and misleading. It's a horrific idea, but it can be done. If you're working at an actual job, it will mean that your coworkers hate you and you'll end up being fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any behavior can be given to the operators.

The recommendation is, however, to avoid overloading operators unless they have the usual meaning.

Sometimes libraries use operators to create small Domain Specific Languages (DSLs), but one must balance brevity and readability.